# Carregar produtos no Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Alguém sabe me dizer uma maneira de estar carregando os produtos do woocommerce, a partir de um banco de dados já existente.

Ex.: o Woocommerce faria apenas a leitura do banco.

Answer (score 2):

Se você quer ignorar o banco de dados do WordPress, o WooCommerce conta hooks e filtros que podem ser utilizados para isso. Claro que você vai perder muitas funções internas e vai ter que reescrever a maioria, mas é possível sim.

A melhor opção é usar o WooCommerce normalmente com o banco de dados do WordPress e usar a API dele para atualizar o seu banco de dados externo, ou através de um wpcron ou através de hooks. A documentação do WooCommerce é muito bem detalhada e tem ganchos e filtros para quase todas as funções.

Outra opção é sincronizar os dois bancos de dados através de exportações em xml ou csv. Antes da API era a única forma de integrar o WooCommerce com um ERP por exemplo. Dá menos trabalho mas o sistema fica mais numa gambiarra do que integrado de fato. Um bom plugin para isso é o Woocommerce csv import, disponível no repositório do WordPress.

A documentação da API: [API](http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs)